# Add .php to end of all WordPress Pages (multisite)

Tags: php, plugin-development, multisite

I have a need for adding .php to the end of all pages created in my WordPress multisite, I tried adding the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/dot-php-pages/ to my network without any success (it does say its outdated) any help here would be greatly appreciated. I am going to start digging into the code behind that plugin but in the meantime if anyone has a solution that would be great.

Comment: What about setting `%postname%.php` as your custom permalink structure?

Comment: This doesn't apply to pages only posts.